# HashMap Storing only one entry

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm taking a binary String like this:

> 010010010000110100001010

as a String, converting it to Integer Array like this:

```
int[] DD = new DD[binString.length()];
       char temp = binString.charAt(i);
        int binData = Character.getNumericValue(temp);
        DD[i] = binData;
```

and I'm tying to save these Integer values in to HashMap(I have to store into a HashMap as per instructions given to me) like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> toMemory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<binString.length();i++) {
        char temp = binString.charAt(i);
        int binData = Character.getNumericValue(temp);
        DD[i] = binData;
        if((DD[i] & (DD[i]-1) ) == 0) {
            toMemory.put(new String("ON"), new Integer(DD[i]));
        } else {
            toMemory.put(new String("ON"), new Integer(DD[i]));
        }
    }
    for(String s: toMemory.keySet()) {
        if(s.startsWith("ON")) {
            System.out.println(toMemory.get(s));
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing here is that, only one entry is being stored in the HashMap, say {"ON",0}. And no other values are being stored. My expected output is this:

> {"ON" , 1 , "OFF" , 0, "ON" , 1 .........}

Is there any better way to store the values to get my expected output? Any help will be much appreciated.

P.S: Please ignore the recurring code, and I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: Note: you *almost never* need to invoke `new String("some string")`, as `"some string"` is already a string just use the literal directly. Similarly, you rarely need to invoke `new Integer(123)`, because 1) this doesn't use the cached instances that are available (use `Integer.valueOf(123)` instead); 2) autoboxing will do it for you: just use `123`.

Comment: Your conditional `if ((DD[i]` etc is redundant: the true and false branches are identical.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I want to check wether a "Bit" is set or not before I insert values into HashMap, could you please suggest me a way to do that @AndyTurner?

Comment: `int[] DD = new DD[binString.length()];` definitely will not compile.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a HashMap. You must have misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: @khelwood  Thank you for your response, my program is working just fine, no compilation issues. I can only store one value inside the HashMap, that's the only issue I'm facing right now.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you for your time sir. I just went through your blog, it's really informative. But, if I can debug every single line of code and understand how each and every line is supposed to work, I need only ask any questions. I will be a programming-pro in no time. Sure enough, debugging is a great way to learn, but in addition to that I  prefer to learn this way too, that's why I keep asking questions.

Comment: @shmosel, you are absolutely right! Somehow I overlooked on a simple fact, thank you! Could you please suggest any alternatives ?

Comment: For what? It's not clear what your goal is.

Comment: @shmosel check if a bet is set or not, and then store it inside a HashMap.

Comment: How should it be stored in the HashMap?

Comment: @AmithAdiraju Your real code may compile. The code you've posted here definitely will not.

Comment: @shmosel the values should be either 0 or 1, but I'm a bit fuzzy about the Key part( as you pointed out). I'm not really sure how to go about it, the motivation to store it in HashMap is for quicker access ( as per my knowledge).

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help. We don't know what the assignment is.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is flawed. Maps take a unique key and return a value. 
You are trying to use duplicate keys. Instead, look at using a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) with a wrapper class:

```
class ClassName {
   public String status;
   public int value; 
   public ClassName(String status, int value){
       this.status = status;
       this.value = value;
   }
}

List<ClassName> list = new ArrayList();
```

To add to the list, create a new instance of your class and call [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-):

```
list.add(new ClassName("ON", 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

as Infuzed Guy said, you are using the `Map` the wrong way. It's a unique "key to value mapping".
As long as you are using several times the same key and want to store all the dada, you need to use a `List`.

Here is what I could come up with the little you gave us: [test it here](https://repl.it/L8FN/1)

```
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            class Tuple<X, Y> {    //The wrapper object
                public final X x;
                public final Y y;

                public Tuple(X x, Y y) {    //Object constructor
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                }

                public String toString()    //Here for printing purpose
                {
                    return "\"" + this.x + "\", " + this.y;
                }
            }

            //Note here te use of List
            List<Tuple> toMemory = new LinkedList<>();

            String binString = "10100100101100101011";
            int[] DD = new int[binString.length()];

            for(int i=0; i < binString.length(); ++i)
            {
                //Here I use the char value 
                //to get the by subtraction
                DD[i] = binString.charAt(i) - '0';
                if(DD[i] == 1)    //Simple check with the int value
                {
                    toMemory.add(new Tuple<>("ON", DD[i]));
                }
                else
                {
                    toMemory.add(new Tuple<>("OFF", DD[i]));
                }
            }

            //Print the List
            System.out.print("{ ");
            for(Tuple s: toMemory) {
                System.out.print(s +", ");
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }
```